# Converting Image to Black and White vs Converting Image to Monochrome(Grey Levels) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

I have the image below `filename = '1.png'`:

[image]

Whenever, I tried converting it to monochrome using the code below, the image is just the same as the input image.

```
image_counter = 1
path = 'sample/' + str(image_counter) + '.png'
image = Image.open(path).convert('L')  # Convert it into monochrome.
image = Image.fromarray(image)
image.save('monochrome.png')
```

Monochrome Output:

[image]

But when i convert it to a black and white image, the output is different and produces not straight borders.

```
image_counter = 1
path = 'sample/' + str(image_counter) + '.png'
image = Image.open(path).convert('1')  # Convert it into black and white.
image = Image.fromarray(image)
image.save('blackandwhite.png')
```

[image]

When zoomed, you can really observed the not straight borders.

[image]

Why is it?

Answer (score 3):

> The default method of converting a greyscale (“L”) or “RGB” image into
>   a bilevel (mode “1”) image **uses Floyd-Steinberg dither** to approximate
>   the original image luminosity levels. If dither is NONE, all non-zero
>   values are set to 255 (white).
>
> Dithering method, used when converting from mode “RGB” to “P” or from
>   “RGB” or “L” to “1”. Available methods are NONE or FLOYDSTEINBERG
>   (default).